# How to remove/add and entry in zip file using SharpCompress in WinRT 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, sharpcompress

as simple as my title says, haven't found any code example and I'm not able to infer the correct use for adding or removing an entry in z zip file.

Basically I'm getting an error in "zip.SaveTo(..." as I don't know how to write this instruction.

Any code example for removing / adding an entry?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out SharpCompress cannot create a new zip file with password in WINRT :(
It can extract password protected but not to Compress password protected.

Comment: Did you find a solution to create a password protected ZIP file? Is there any other library which passes the Microsoft Certification Kit?

Comment: Sorry... didn't find anything.